# How to fix intermittent car horn?

Tags: steering-wheel, intermittent-problems, horn

Sometimes my horn works sometimes it doesn't. This has been going on for a few months now.

Is this an easy diy fix?  What might the cause be, what things should I look into?

If I have to open up the steering wheel, is there anything I need to be aware of like air bag being released, I think I read somewhere that might happen if you open the steering wheel.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the car and how the horn functions. It should function through a relay. If it is working intermittently, then the wiring *should* be okay, but isn't a given. You have the horn button, relay, power, or ground connections which might be at fault. You can check the horn directly by attaching a 12vdc source directly to it. I'd start checking at the horn and work your way back, ensuring everything is golden as you go.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The electrician's lament : whichever end you start , the fault is at the other end... :)